# React-Native Deeplinks with React-Navigation not working

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I've been trying to set the deeplinks for my app, via react-navigation (v5) so I followed their instructions. I've edited my app delegate to include the package I need and the deeplinking/ universal methods, which i copy pasted from their website.
After that they said to add the scheme to the project's configuration so i followed what they said and wrote
`npx uri-scheme add playlist --ios` in the terminal, I can confirm it works because I can do `npx uri-scheme list` and I get back

```
› iOS: Schemes for config: ./ios/audvice-tvOS/Info.plist
› playlist://

› Android: Schemes for config: ./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
› ${applicationId}://
› ${applicationId}://
› ${applicationId}://
› https://
```

And now I'd just have to test it by running either `npx uri-scheme open playlist://asdf --ios`  or `xcrun simctl openurl booted playlist://asdf`, when I do that I get back the following error:

```
› iOS: Attempting to open URI "playlist://1234" in simulator
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code=-10814):
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

Aborting run
An unexpected error was encountered. Please report it as a bug:
Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 194
    at ChildProcess.d (/Users/chris/.npm/_npx/50946/lib/node_modules/uri-scheme/build/index.js:1:3255)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (/Users/chris/.npm/_npx/50946/lib/node_modules/uri-scheme/build/index.js:1:2740)
    at Object.openAsync (/Users/chris/.npm/_npx/50946/lib/node_modules/uri-scheme/build/index.js:1:261648)
    at Object.openAsync (/Users/chris/.npm/_npx/50946/lib/node_modules/uri-scheme/build/index.js:1:314115)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/chris/.npm/_npx/50946/lib/node_modules/uri-scheme/build/index.js:1:136332)
    at Command.i (/Users/chris/.npm/_npx/50946/lib/node_modules/uri-scheme/build/index.js:1:281412)
    at Command.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Command.parseArgs (/Users/chris/.npm/_npx/50946/lib/node_modules/uri-scheme/build/index.js:1:284584)
    at Command.parse (/Users/chris/.npm/_npx/50946/lib/node_modules/uri-scheme/build/index.js:1:282539)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chris/.npm/_npx/50946/lib/node_modules/uri-scheme/cli.js:5:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30) {
  pid: 50949,
  output: [ '', '' ],
  stdout: '',
  stderr: '',
  status: 194,
  signal: null
}
```

Has anyone ever encountered that before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like a compilation error in the AppDelegate.m, have you tried to execute react-native run-ios to see if it builds properly? Did you add the `#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>`at the top of the file?

Comment: Not OP's problem but in case it helps others: do not use numbers in your scheme, only letters (otherwise it will crash on iOS with a similar error message).

Comment: I have numbers in my schemes and I dont have any issues

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue / error.
You need to run the application and then the deep linking will work.
This means that you actually have no application bundle, so it will not find your app to open the deep link.